# Finding the mathematical function is plotted by using the bodeplot command

Tags: plotting, control-systems

I've the following code:

```
BodePlot[{1/(((5.601443110900379`*^-8)*(5.601443110900379`*^-8)*(1.\
6672176431702952`*^-7)*(56000)*(56000 + 
          56000)*((56000*56000)/(56000 + 56000)))*(2*Pi*f*
         I)^3 + ((5.601443110900379`*^-8)*(5.601443110900379`*^-8)*(\
56000)*(56000 + 
           56000) + \
(5.601443110900379`*^-8)*(1.6672176431702952`*^-7)*(56000)*(56000 + 
           56000))*(2*Pi*f*
         I)^2 + ((5.601443110900379`*^-8)*(56000) + \
(5.601443110900379`*^-8)*(56000 + 56000 + 56000))*(2*Pi*f*I) + 
     1)}, {f, 0, 100}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {{"Linear", "dB"}, {"Linear", "Degree"}}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

This code gives two plots, the amplitude and the phase.

> How can I find the function that is plotted as the phase? I mean can I aks Mathematica what kind of function (exp, arctan, arccos or arcsin etc.) it has plotted to plot the phase?

Comment: The phase should be `Arg`. So try your formula with a simple `Plot` and wrap `Arg` around it. Since this will give values from -Pi to Pi, you need to process this. You could use `toDegree[arg_] := Mod[arg, 2 Pi]/(2 Pi)*360` or you set `ScalingFunctions` appropriately.